# Selecting fields in SQL Select statements (Dumbest SQL Question)

Tags: sql, select, field

Here's a dumb question which I can't find an answer to:
I have a table which contains 20 fields, a few of which are date/time. I am interested in pulling all the fields. I would like to pull the datetime fields using the to_char function but don't want to individually list out all the other fields. Is there an easy way to do this?

I tried `select *, tochar(dtfield) as dt2` and `select tochar(dtfield) as dt2, *` and both give errors.

Thanks for all your help!
JC

Comment: Of course you should never use selct * anyway. List only the fileds you need, always. Select * creates maintenance issues, it's slower and it wastes resources when you have joins and it sends the join field information twice.

Comment: @HLGEM Did it occur to you that he needs all the columns?

Comment: @monadic, It doesn't matter if you need all the columns, you should not ever use select * in production code. It makes performance worse and makes it harder to maintain as you may get things in a differnt order later or add columns you don't want users to see. If you have even one join you are sending unnede information across the network which is a waste of Server and database resources. It is an extremely poor programming practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to qualify the * with the table name (or alias):

```
select tablename.*, tochar(dtfield) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got no `from` clause that you've shared.  You have to select *from* a table, did you just omit it in your example?